# Singleton Pattern - Splash Screen Not Launching After app being Killed (Memory Release) by OS Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Singleton pattern. When application goes into background the OS kills the app to release memory. When user comes back to app my application starts from same Activity User left off but my singleton instance is not available because it was released too when OS released memory.
Suppose I am at Activity 5 and I have values int a = singleton.getInt() it will give me a null pointer exception. Other local views initialized are null too. But if my application restarts from splash screen then its all good because app flow is starting from scratch. Sometimes it starts from Splash, some times it goes to Activity 5 or whatever activity User left off (which will cause null pointer exception). I have used a lifecycle Observer to monitor application state in MainApplication but what exactly is the root of this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You've answered yourself what "the root of this issue" was: _"When application goes into background the OS kills the app to release memory"_. You should handle the case when navigating back to the app cause the system would instantiate and bring to top the Activity that was on top of the backstack when the app got killed.

Comment: I did handled the case I added lifecycle Observer in Main Application to monitor app states and handled my issue there. But I am still not convinced why it is happening in singleton pattern and not the other patterners i am using?

Comment: What did you expect in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Like any other scenario my application should start from Launcher screen or Splash screen but its not it starts from same activity User left off

Comment: _"but its not it starts from same activity User left off"_ This is how the system acts when killing an app and navigating back to it. So you have to handle this scenario by navigating to "Launcher screen or Splash screen" from the "same activity User left off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why does this happen?

When the system kills your application to free the memory it saves a few pieces of data about the current state of your Application into the internal OS storage. Later on, when the user opens your app once again, the system takes that saved data from the storage and tries to restore the state of the Application.

The reason for that behavior is to make the user experience smoother. By restoring the state - the user can quickly continue doing things he was doing before quitting your application.

Some of the data that is stored in the OS storage:

- Activities back stack (back stack of the Task)
- FragmentManagers back stack
- Bundle that you saved in the `onSaveInstanceState` methods

**Please note:** ViewModels are not saved between application re-creation. Even though they are saved upon Activity recreation(configuration change, such as screen rotation). So data that you store inside of your ViewModels (if any) would be lost!

In order to support this OS feature and ensure a smooth user experience in your application, you must design your application to not depend on any Launcher Activity to instantiate your singletons and instead use some other architectural approach that would not require your Launcher Screen to launch every time the application restarts.

### What can you do?

You could try one of the following:

- Save all the user input data (if any) to the Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` method.
- Migrate from Splash Screen Activity or Launcher Activity in favor of the Reactive approach to data instantiation.
- Move your Singleton instantiation to Application class. Note: This could significantly increase the launch time of your application.

That is by no means an exhaustive list of actions you could do. I bet you would have better ideas that are applicable to your own application.

If migrating away from Launcher Activity is not possible at the moment, I suggest adding to your Activity `onCreate` method a check that everything is instantiated and ready to use. If not - immediately navigate the user to your Launcher Activity.

**Please note:** It would be good UX to save back stack and navigate back to the current activity as soon as your logic on Launcher Activity is done working.